# FFT result relationship when padding with different amount of zeros?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

Suppose I have a list `a=[1,2,3,4]` and have already calculated its DFT: `fft(a)=[10.+0.j, -2.+2.j, -2.+0.j, -2.-2.j]`.

Now I'd like to pad `a` with different amount of zeros to `b` (pad with two zeros): `b=[1,2,3,4,0,0]` and want to find `fft(b)`. Is there an **efficient** way to reuse the result of `fft(a)` to get `fft(b)`? by efficient I mean it's faster than directly calculate `fft(b)`

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: The FFT is generally defined for $2^n$ points.

Comment: No. Unless you add $length(a)\ m$ zeros in which case you already computed $1/(m+1)$-th of the values of the fft. It is particularly obvious when taking $a(n)=1$ so that its fft it a single peak at $0$ whereas the fft of $b$ is a $sin(\pi m x)/\sin(\pi x)$